# How to use Angular2 with JSPM?

Tags: angular, typescript, jspm

I've been using Angular2 With JSPM (v17), but the only way I've been able to get it to work is to configure typescript to compile my modules as `commonjs`. However, in doing so, I always see the following warning for each file:

> TypeScript [Warning] transpiling to CommonJS, consider setting module: "system" in typescriptOptions to transpile directly to System.register format

When I set module to `system` I get the following runtime error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined

Which is being thrown from this bit of code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If I remove my routing module from the project, I end up seeing the following error:

> core_1.Component is not a function

Around my `AppComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>hello world</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Apparently, any Angular imports are coming back as `null`.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "jspm_packages"
    ]
}
```

I've also tried overriding the format for all `@angular` packages to `esm`, but then I see the following runtime error:

> Can't add property ng, object is not extensible

Is `commonjs` the only way to go or am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 2):

From [Guy Bedford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42611789/1110395):

> Yes this was a change in SystemJS 0.20 where named exports for non-ES
>   modules are no longer supported, in order to align with how interop
>   will work in NodeJS between ES modules and CommonJS, which is to only
>   provide compatibility with the default import form - import module
>   from 'module' (equivalent to import {default as module} from
>   'module').

To include CommonJS modules with named exports, I needed to add an override to each angular library, including any other third-party libraries that were commonjs.

```
"meta": {
  "*.js": {
    "esModule": true
  }
}
```

For now, it seems the best to just set typescript to use `commonjs` as the module system.